# Is my proof that a short exact sequence of sheaves gives a left-exact sequence of global sections ok?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

While understanding prop 5.6, II, Hartshorne, I try to solve the additional exercise : Let $0 \to \mathcal{F}' \to \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F''} \to 0 $ be a short exact sequence(SES), then global section is left-exact functor . i.e,  $0 \to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}') \to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}) \to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}'')  $.

My sketch of proof is here : Suppose $0 \to  \mathcal{F}' \overset{\phi} {\to} \mathcal{F} \overset{\psi} {\to} \mathcal{F''} \to 0 $ is SES, then claim is obviously, i) $\overset{\sim}{\phi}: \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}') \to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})$ is injective, ii) $Ker ~\overset{\sim} {\psi}= Im ~\overset{\sim} {\phi} $  (Of course, $\overset{\sim} {\psi}:  \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}) \to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}'')  $)[But, my intersting on this question is only i)].

*( The following  is also my thought)*
i) is equivalent to $ker~\overset{\sim} {\phi} = 0$. Thus, I assume $ker~\overset{\sim} {\phi} \neq 0$, i.e there is a **nonzero** function $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}') $ s.t, $\overset{\sim} {\phi}(s)=0$. Let $\left \{ V_{i} \right \}$ be a open covering of $X$. Then, by (contrapostive) condition of sheaf,  $s|_{V_i} \neq 0$ for some $i$,  then since $s|_{V_i} \in \mathcal{F}'(V_i)$ and $\phi$ is injective by assumption, $\phi(s|_{V_i}) \in \mathcal{F}(V_i)$ is cannot be zero for some $i$, Hence  $0 \neq \overset{\sim} {\phi}(s) \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}) $ This contradicts to the assumption.

However, clearly, my proof seems to have many flaws. Personally, the reason I cannot prove the above completely is that I cannot surely understand what is the **morphism of sheaves is exact sequence**.  The definition of morphism is sheaves is clear: If $U,V (V \subset U)$ are open subset of $X$, and ( $\mathcal{F}$ and $ \mathcal{F'}$ are obviously sheaves) Then, $\phi : \mathcal{F}' \to  \mathcal{F} $ is a morphism of sheaves means [diagram is commutative something like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#Morphisms). But what is such morphism is exact? My thought is that the following diagram holds... But is it the right idea?

[image]

Comment: A exact sequence of sheaves is the same as in any abelian category, that means that kernel and images of adjacent morphisms coincide. The kernel of a morphism of sheaf is what you think it is (e.g the same as the kernel as presheaf), but for the image you need to take a sheafification. Of course as the sheafification preserves stalks, saying that an exact sequence of sheaves is exact is tantamount to saying that it is exact on stalks. Therefore you can "interpret" the exactness as the fact that all stalk short sequences, are exact. Use this and you can prove your result.

Comment: In particular, the diagram you joined in the picture, need not have exact rows, even if the short sequence is exact.